# Construct a ring isomorphism and prove it is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

$\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)= a + b\sqrt3,\; a, b \in \Bbb Q$

Let $S$ denote $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q$ with normal addition and multiplication.

Construct a ring isomorphism $\phi: \Bbb Q(\sqrt3) \to S$. Prove $S$ is a field.

I can prove that $S$ is a field but I have no idea how to even begin constructing this ring isomorphism?

Comment: $S$ can't be a field, as $(1,0) \cdot (0,1) = (0,0)$, so there are zero-divisors. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I took it to understand addition and multiplication were defined by:

Comment: (a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d) and (a,b)(c,d)=(ac+3cd,ad+bc)

Comment: If they haven't specified anything, then the "normal" multiplication on $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q$ would be component-wise, in my opinion. But yes, with the multiplication you have there, the isomorphism is as simple as you can imagine.

Comment: So how would I construct that ring isomorphism with the multiplication I have definied above?

Comment: What do you think $1 + 0\sqrt 3$ should be mapped to, and what should $0 + 1\sqrt3$ be mapped to, if I say it's supposed to be the simplest way you can imagine? Even if that isn't the right answer, it should always be the first thing you try.

Answer (score 0):

The addition in $S$ is componentwise,
$$(a+\sqrt{3} b) + (c+\sqrt{3}d) =(a+c,b+d).$$
But the multiplication is a bit twisted:
$$(a+\sqrt{3} b) \cdot (c+\sqrt{3}d) =(ac+3bd,ad+bc).$$

Comment: By QxQ i mean the rationals by the rationals and not the set Q{$\sqrt3$],